# Next js typescript openai API Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'completions')

Tags: typescript, next.js, openai-api

I'm trying to use the openai API in next js 14 but I keep getting an error saying Uncaught (in promise):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'completions').

This is my config.ts file

```
'use server'
import OpenAI from "openai"


const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
})

export default openai
```

This is my actions.ts file

```
import openai from "@/config/openai"
export const generateRecommendations = async () => {
    const content = "test";
    const data = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      messages: [{ role: "user", content }],
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo'
    })

    return data
    
}
```

This is where I'm trying to log the data

```
import { fetchAnimeInfo, generateRecommendations } from '@/server-actions/actions';
const getRecommendations = async () => {
    const data = await generateRecommendations();
    console.log(data)

  }

//button onclick
```

Comment: what version `openai` package?

Comment: @Yilmaz version 4.24.1

Comment: is `process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY` correct. can you log it to the console in your config file

Comment: @Yilmaz Even when I change process.env for the actual api key, the same error still comes up